# Differentiate between Tokyo and Seoul Timezone

Tags: javascript, timezone

I need to differentiate between Tokyo and Seoul Timezone, both have the same Offset and not DST offset.

I am using javascript to calculate the offsets. Also looked at parsing the string to get the name of timezone and it does not seem like a good idea.

Please let me know how the two can be differentiated.

Comment: Differentiate them where, in what context?

Comment: "parsing the string to get the name", what string?

Comment: Why do you actually have to distinguish between the two timezones?

Comment: My JavaScript function returns me timezone Offset and DST offset. On receiving these offset my php function determines the Timezone.            Both Tokyo and Seoul return the same offset i.e. 32400 and no DST.      So how do I determine the timezone now

Comment: Wikipedia says: there is no difference between the zones JST and KST: both are UTC+9 and both don't have daylight saving time. What is it you want to achieve? Finding out where someone comes from?

Comment: Yes, I need to find which timezone the User belongs to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Date()` seems to include the timezone name.

For Tokyo it returns:

```
Thu May 31 2012 21:09:04 GMT+0900 (JST)
```

For Seoul it returns:

```
Thu May 31 2012 21:09:04 GMT+0900 (KST)
```

However, this depends on the browser / OS.

Otherwise you could try to determine the user's geolocation (based on IP address) or provide the user with a list of regions / areas in his or her timezone to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

If Offset and DST are the *only* information you have and they are the *same* in both cases, you obviously **cannot** differentiate them.

Hence, you will need another piece of information. The name of the timezone, which you seem to be able to extract from a timestring, sounds to be a good identifier. You should use the official name from the [zone.tab file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone.tab).

You should not rely on Date's [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) or [`toTimeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toTimeString), they are [specified](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.5.2) to be implementation-dependent.

Comment: Please clarify on the following:                                          - Will different browsers return the string differently? If Yes, how do we parse it?                                                               - The clients local time is picked up by the javascript. Suppose my OS is not english say German etc will the same string be returned?

Comment: Which string? You didn't show us any code where a browser returns a string.

Comment: Date() function in JavaScript returns the timezone name e.g.  Sun May 06 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (Tokyo Standard Time). But I think it is browser as well as OS dependent not sure though.

Comment: Ah, you should have come up with this in your question.

Comment: What are the other ways of extracting a time string?